# Get most Senior

Tags: javascript, arrays

friends!
I need your help.

A list of information about people is given.

An array containing the oldest person in the list must be returned. If several people are of the same highest age, then an array should be returned containing all of them.

The age is stored in the "age" field.

Input data:

```
const data =[
    { firstName: 'Gabriel', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Monaco', continent: 'Europe', age: 49, language: 'PHP' },
    { firstName: 'Odval', lastName: 'F.', country: 'Mongolia', continent: 'Asia', age: 38, language: 'Python' },
    { firstName: 'Emilija', lastName: 'S.', country: 'Lithuania', continent: 'Europe', age: 19, language: 'Python' },
    { firstName: 'Sou', lastName: 'B.', country: 'Japan', continent: 'Asia', age: 49, language: 'PHP' },
]

const result = getMostSenior(data);
```

Output data:

```
console.log(result);
// [
//     { firstName: 'Gabriel', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Monaco', continent: 'Europe', age: 49, language: 'PHP' },
//     { firstName: 'Sou', lastName: 'B.', country: 'Japan', continent: 'Asia', age: 49, language: 'PHP' },
// ]
```

My try:

```
const getMostSenior = humans => {

    let oldestHuman = humans.reduce((oldest, human) => {
        return oldest.age > human.age ? oldest : human;
    })
    return oldestHuman  
};
```

But this only returns an array containing the oldest person in the list.

Can't figure out how to return an array where multiple people have the same maximum age.

Please, help.

Comment: You've already found `oldestHuman` which is the oldest person (or tied for oldest).  Now just return `humans.filter(h => h.age === oldestHuman.age);`

Answer (score 0):

This is not an efficient implementation though!

```js
function getMostSenior(data){

  const ageArray = [];
  const agedPersons = {};
  data.forEach((item)=>{
    const age = item.age;
    ageArray.push(age);
    if(agedPersons.hasOwnProperty(age)){
      agedPersons[age].push(item);
    }
    else{
      agedPersons[age] = [];
      agedPersons[age].push(item);
    }
  });
  ageArray.sort();
  return [...agedPersons[ageArray[ageArray.length-1]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing the *object* to the accumulator you should return only the *age*. You can then use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the data to get all those objects where the age matches the value of that variable.

```js
const data=[{firstName:"Gabriel",lastName:"X.",country:"Monaco",continent:"Europe",age:49,language:"PHP"},{firstName:"Odval",lastName:"F.",country:"Mongolia",continent:"Asia",age:38,language:"Python"},{firstName:"Emilija",lastName:"S.",country:"Lithuania",continent:"Europe",age:19,language:"Python"},{firstName:"Sou",lastName:"B.",country:"Japan",continent:"Asia",age:49,language:"PHP"}];

function getMostSenior(data) {
  const oldest = data.reduce((oldest, c) => {
    return c.age > oldest ? c.age : oldest;
  }, 0);
  return data.filter(obj => obj.age === oldest);
}

console.log(getMostSenior(data));
```

The alternative to using `reduce` for this task would be to use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to iterate over the array and update a variable if the age value of an object is greater than the current value of the variable.

```js
const data=[{firstName:"Gabriel",lastName:"X.",country:"Monaco",continent:"Europe",age:49,language:"PHP"},{firstName:"Odval",lastName:"F.",country:"Mongolia",continent:"Asia",age:38,language:"Python"},{firstName:"Emilija",lastName:"S.",country:"Lithuania",continent:"Europe",age:19,language:"Python"},{firstName:"Sou",lastName:"B.",country:"Japan",continent:"Asia",age:49,language:"PHP"}];

function getMostSenior(data) {
  let oldest = 0;
  for (const { age } of data) {
    if (age > oldest) oldest = age;
  }
  return data.filter(obj => obj.age === oldest);
}

console.log(getMostSenior(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is little optimal way to solve your problem using [Array Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var data =[
    { firstName: 'Gabriel', lastName: 'X.', country: 'Monaco', continent: 'Europe', age: 49, language: 'PHP' },
    { firstName: 'Odval', lastName: 'F.', country: 'Mongolia', continent: 'Asia', age: 38, language: 'Python' },
    { firstName: 'Emilija', lastName: 'S.', country: 'Lithuania', continent: 'Europe', age: 19, language: 'Python' },
    { firstName: 'Sou', lastName: 'B.', country: 'Japan', continent: 'Asia', age: 49, language: 'PHP' },
];


var output = data.reduce((a, c) => {

  if (a.length) {
    if (a[0].age < c.age)
      a = [c];
    else if (a[0].age == c.age)
      a.push(c)
  } else {
    a = [c];
  }

  return a;

}, []);

console.log(output);
```